# Get a callback when user dismisses an Intent dialog

Tags: android, android-intent

I have a video player that displays ads. When I click on the video player I fire a Intent that opens a URL. However, if there's many apps that can handle that Intent, a dialog is displayed. Is there a reliable way to know if the user has dismissed that dialog so I can resume the ad?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will do the trick:

Fire the intent using `startActivityForResult`, like this

```
private static final Integer OPEN_BROWSER_REQUEST_CODE = 100;

[...]

Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"));
startActivityForResult(browserIntent, OPEN_BROWSER_REQUEST_CODE);
```

and then catch the result by overriding `onActivityResult`, like this

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == OPEN_BROWSER_REQUEST_CODE) {
        switch (resultCode) {
            case RESULT_OK:
                break;
            case RESULT_CANCELED:
                break;
        }
    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

You must be launching the `Intent` like this:

```
startActivity(intent);
```

You need to launch it like this:

```
static final int OPEN_AD = 1234;
startActivityForResult(intent, OPEN_AD);
```

and catch the dismissal in

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == OPEN_AD) {

        /* If user dismisses diaog */
        if (resultCode =! RESULT_OK) {

            /* display ad again etc... */
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @santirivera92: you're welcome, of course :) sorry for replying so late. However, I answered your question first, before `Joao Sousa` did. I think its only fair that this answer be marked correct. I request you to do that ... thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Opening the picker dialog will call the `onPause()` method of the Activity. Closing it will call the `onResume()` method.

Simply pause and resume your ad video in those methods.

Comment: Those methods will be called in a lot of different places and I cannot rely on them for specific functionality.

Comment: Yes you can, it is just a matter of a well-designed flow, with triggers and checks in the right places :-)